# delete google group member via GAS + AdminDirectory API

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm looking a way to programmatically manage google groups membership in our google apps for business domain.

I found the add member works:

```
function addGroupMember() {
  var userEmail = 'user@example.com';
  var groupEmail = 'group@example.com';
  var member = {
    email: userEmail,
    role: 'MEMBER'
  };
  member = AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupEmail);
  Logger.log('User %s added as a member of group %s.', userEmail, groupEmail);
}
```

but i have error when i try to write code to delete a googlegroup's member

```
function deleteGroupMember() {
  var userEmail = 'user@example.com';
  var groupEmail = 'group@example.com';


  var return = AdminDirectory.Members.delete(userEmail, groupEmail);
  Logger.log('User %s deleted from group %s.', userEmail, groupEmail);
}
```

wnen i try to save the code below i have this error:
Missing name after the operator(.). (line 33, file "Codice")
line 33 = var return = AdminDirectory.Members.delete(userEmail, groupEmail);

This is my first use for API in GAS, and whitout an example i could have missed the sintiax.

Do you have the correct one? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `delete` method for `adminDirectory.Members` but instead use

`AdminDirectory.Members.remove(groupKey, memberKey);// keys = emails`

note also that this method returns nothing so there is no need to begin with `var xxx = ...` , write it directly as above.

Comment: WOW! It works!  Thanks! but i found members.delete in admin sdk reference https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/delete, but no trace for members.remove! may be i'm looking in the wrong place

Comment: use the autocomplete feature in the script editor to help you finding the suitable methods. And please consider accepting the answer.thx

Comment: Of course i accept your answer... but autocopletion doesnt work, i.m using Chrome to edit project in drive...

Comment: yes autocompletion works for me too.. just I was using the dot key fron the numeric keyboard :-( discovered it is not the same thing

Comment: @uffa14 Just ran into the exact same problem, except my GAS is running in an AppMaker app. It's confounding that the API methods work *almost* all the time...

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced

> Methods named delete in the Google API are named remove in Apps Script, since delete is a reserved word in JavaScript.